# Gradle build failed with error com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting problem building Gradle. Getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqb.class
```

Here I have pasted my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

    dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}


repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"          }
}


 android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

}

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nbourses.oyeok"
    minSdkVersion 18
    multiDexEnabled true
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 19
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-library-2.4.0.jar')
compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.10.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

//compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.1.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.3@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.diegocarloslima:fgelv:0.1.+@aar'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
compile 'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.1.0'
compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.10.2'
compile 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.5'
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.1'
compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.+'
compile 'com.cleveroad:androidmanimation:0.9.0'
compile 'com.instabug.library:instabug:2.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```

Any idea how to fix it? I was just trying to update android studio, initially it was working fine.

Comment: please show your gradle file

Comment: Probably caused by duplication Packaging option. Did you add new libraries to your gradle? Try removing the packaging option from Build.Gradle

Comment: I have added gradle file